# Vivado constraints file error

Tags: constraints, vhdl, vivado

I am trying to run a program that should mimic a MIPS and I am having problems concerning the constraint file. [the error and warnings I get when synthesizing
and Implementing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izf5O.png) 
These are the constraints for Basys 3 board which I use. 
Also this error appeared on Vivado 2017 and Vivado 2016. I have checked this on two different laptops.

```sh
# This file is a general .xdc for the Basys3 rev B board
# To use it in a project:
# - uncomment the lines corresponding to used pins
# - rename the used ports (in each line, after get_ports) according to the top level signal names in the project

# Clock signal
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W5 [get_ports clk]                         
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports clk]
    #create_clock -add -name sys_clk_pin -period 10.00 -waveform {0 5} [get_ports clk]

# Switches
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V17 [get_ports {sw[0]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V16 [get_ports {sw[1]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W16 [get_ports {sw[2]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W17 [get_ports {sw[3]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[3]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W15 [get_ports {sw[4]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[4]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V15 [get_ports {sw[5]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[5]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W14 [get_ports {sw[6]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[6]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W13 [get_ports {sw[7]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[7]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V2 [get_ports {sw[8]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[8]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T3 [get_ports {sw[9]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[9]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T2 [get_ports {sw[10]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[10]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN R3 [get_ports {sw[11]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[11]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W2 [get_ports {sw[12]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[12]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U1 [get_ports {sw[13]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[13]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T1 [get_ports {sw[14]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[14]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN R2 [get_ports {sw[15]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sw[15]}]


# LEDs
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U16 [get_ports {led[0]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN E19 [get_ports {led[1]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U19 [get_ports {led[2]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V19 [get_ports {led[3]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[3]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W18 [get_ports {led[4]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[4]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U15 [get_ports {led[5]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[5]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U14 [get_ports {led[6]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[6]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V14 [get_ports {led[7]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[7]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V13 [get_ports {led[8]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[8]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V3 [get_ports {led[9]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[9]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W3 [get_ports {led[10]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[10]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U3 [get_ports {led[11]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[11]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN P3 [get_ports {led[12]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[12]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN N3 [get_ports {led[13]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[13]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN P1 [get_ports {led[14]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[14]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN L1 [get_ports {led[15]}]                   
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {led[15]}]


#7 catment display
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W7 [get_ports {cat[0]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {cat[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W6 [get_ports {cat[1]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {cat[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U8 [get_ports {cat[2]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {cat[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V8 [get_ports {cat[3]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {cat[3]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U5 [get_ports {cat[4]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {cat[4]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V5 [get_ports {cat[5]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {cat[5]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U7 [get_ports {cat[6]}]                    
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {cat[6]}]



set_property PACKAGE_PIN U2 [get_ports {an[0]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {an[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U4 [get_ports {an[1]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {an[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN V4 [get_ports {an[2]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {an[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W4 [get_ports {an[3]}]                 
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {an[3]}]


#Buttons
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U18 [get_ports {btn[0]}]                       
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {btn[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T18 [get_ports {btn[1]}]                       
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {btn[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W19 [get_ports {btn[2]}]                       
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {btn[2]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T17 [get_ports btn[3]]                     
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {btn[3]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN U17 [get_ports {btn[4]}]                       
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {btn[4]}]
```

*

**

```
entity test_env is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           btn : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           sw : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           led : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
           an : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           cat : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);
           dp : out  STD_LOGIC);
end test_env;
```

Please help me figure this one out! 
I have not run into this error before.

EDIT:
The issue was in the VHDL code. It was made for a Nexys 2 board not Basys 3 and when trying to apply the constraints it wasn't working.
Thank you all !

Comment: it seems `get_ports {sw[8]}` is not returning an object. Are you using that pin in your design? Else you can comment out the lines in the constraints file. You cannot constrain non-existing signals.

Comment: Yes, I am using that pin. I am using all 15 of  sw actually. I have used the same constraint file for a while and before trying this code there were no errors

Comment: Can you add the entity interface of `test_env.vhd`?

Comment: Thanks: but are you *actually using* switch 9 (zero based) inside of the code? Else the port could be optimized away.

Comment: Can you copy paste the error message instead of a screenshot ? Usually, when you're dealing with an error you cannot explain, you ask your favorite search engine with the error message. If the message is in your question, others will have more chance to find an answer.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `dp` port?

Answer (score 0):

Vivado error tells you that :

*"1 out of 27 logical port use I/O standard value 'DEFAULT' [...] **Problem ports: dp**"*.

In your constraint file, all your pins are defined with LVCMOS33. As the pin `dp` is not defined, Vivado will assign to it a 'DEFAULT' I/O Standard value.

To solve it, Add the missing pin like others with the good pin number relative to your board and the same I/O Standard value:

```
set_property PACKAGE_PIN XX [get_ports {dp}]        # replace XX with the pin name defined in your board pinout            
    set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {dp}]
```

Comment: That kind of is the problem, I don't have an empty space for dp on my board. The issue was the code in VHDL. It was made for a Nexis 2 Not Basys 3 and there are pins differences between them.

Comment: @Maria Then remove the output port from the entity? Do you really need it? If yes, you would have a big problem anyway...

Comment: @Maria, JHBonarius is right ! Either this signal is no use and in this case you can remove it from entity, or this signal is mandatory for your design and you'll never be able to make your FPGA to work on board without a workaround.

Comment: Does this atrix-7 pin support LVCMOS33?